# Diagonal length ordering in regular polygon

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Consider a convex regular polygon $A_1A_2\dots A_{2n}$. By drawing, it is pretty clear that $|A_1A_2|\leq |A_1A_3|\leq\dots\leq |A_1A_n|$. But is there a way to see this formally, without messy calculations?

Comment: Use hinge theorem and consider the lines connecting vertices to the center of the regular polygon.

Comment: You need to state that the polygon is convex. Your formula does not hold for regular stars such as the pentagram.

Comment: @GuyInchbald Thanks, stated.

Comment: essentially the same question as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3815989/relationship-of-third-side-of-triangle-to-opposite-angle (when combined with the suggestion to consider the triangles formed when joining vertices to the centre of the regular polygon)