# Relationship of third side of triangle to opposite angle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

In any (Euclidian) triangle with two sides of fixed length, when the angle between them is larger, the opposite side is always longer. Intuitively this seems right, and I found this statement in an old textbook, but I have not found a proof. Can anyone provide a proof?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use the cosine rule: $c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos \theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle opposite the side of length $c$. If $a,b$ are fixed and $\theta$ varies then increasing $\theta$ (in the range $(0,\pi)$) decreases $\cos\theta$ so increases $c^2$ and therefore $c$.

Answer (score 2):

A purely geometrical proof is contained in Euclid's elements, Book 1, proposition 24:

[https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI24.html](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI24.html)

[image]